# Removing exceeding parts of axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is possible to remove exceeding parts (on image in red elipsis) of axis on graph generated by graph.js?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the grid-lines from the scales:

```
yAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  },
}]
```

You won't see any exceeding lines, if you do this for both axes.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1NU5/vramq0en/) for a working demo

If you need the grid-lines and only want to hide the exceeding line at 0, you can set the `zeroLineWidth` to `0`

```
gridLines: {
  zeroLineWidth: 0
}
```

With `tickMarkLength` you can determin how many pixels the grid-lines draw into the axis area.

```
gridLines: {
  tickMarkLength: 0
}
```

If you need more advanced styling of the axis, you can write a plugin. See [Style X and Y Axis (tick mark) with Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153466/style-x-and-y-axis-tick-mark-with-chart-js) for a good start.