# Remove excess lines on y axis using chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I wonder how to remove the excess lines on the line chart. I tried to set `drawborder` to false but of course it just remove the all lines to the axis. I just wanted get rid of the unwanted vertical lines that points to the y axis labels like the image below with red mark.

[image]

Template:

```
<d-chartrecord 
     :chart-data="datacollection" 
     v-bind:options="options"
     :height="200"
></d-chartrecord>
```

Script:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            datacollection: {},
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                  display: false,
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            color: '#D7D7D7'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 8,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 8,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            stepSize: 50,
                            maxTicksLimit: 3
                        }
                    }],
                }
            },

        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.putData()
    },
    methods: {
        putData () {
            this.datacollection = {
                labels: ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],
                datasets: [{
                    lineTension: 0,
                    radius: 4,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#F2A727',
                    pointBackgroundColor:[ '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#F2A727'],
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
                }]
            }
        },
        getRandomInt  () {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (95)) + 5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try this method to change color to transparent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153466/style-x-and-y-axis-tick-mark-with-chart-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any native functionality for this in ChartJS at the moment. You would rather need to create a chart plugin to achieve that.

**ᴘʟᴜɢɪɴ** (ᴅʀᴀᴡ x-ᴀxɪꜱ ɢʀɪᴅ-ʟɪɴᴇꜱ)
­

```
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx,
          x_axis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'],
          topY = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].top,
          bottomY = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
      x_axis.options.gridLines.display = false;
      x_axis.ticks.forEach(function(label, index) {
         if (index === 0) return;
         var x = x_axis.getPixelForValue(label);
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = x_axis.options.gridLines.color;
         ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
         ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      });
   }
});
```

<sup>* place this at the top of your script</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
   beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx,
          x_axis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'],
          topY = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].top,
          bottomY = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
      x_axis.options.gridLines.display = false; // hide original grid-lines
      // loop through x-axis ticks
      x_axis.ticks.forEach(function(label, index) {
         if (index === 0) return;
         var x = x_axis.getPixelForValue(label);
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = x_axis.options.gridLines.color;
         ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
         ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      });
   }
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false,
         tension: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 1
            },
            gridLines: {
               display: false
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this man, just figuring out how to do it using `vue-chartjs`.

Comment: already added the script at the top of where I call the chart data but no luck. I think this is the problem `var ctx = chart.chart.ctx` Please see the sample code I attached on how I call the chart. thanks

Comment: try adding the plugin where you're importing that module (the one in your question)

Comment: Just copying and pasting this code does not work: 'Chart.plugins.register is not a function'. How can I make it work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Klyner Use latest version of ChartJS - 2.6.0

Comment: @ℊααnd This works. But now I have another problem: The first vertical line has been removed, and the other lines are thicker than before..

Comment: @Klyner hm. I see, you have different case. need some modifications to the plugin. will post it on your question after some time.

Comment: @ℊααnd Thank you very much! When I change the pointBorderWidth of my first line to '1', the width is good. But that is not what I want ;)

Answer (score 6):

In chart.js, `gridLines` provides an option `tickMarkLength` to disable the length beyond the axes, Eg:

```
 yAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            tickMarkLength: 0,
          },
        }] 
xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            tickMarkLength: 0,
          },
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

in Chart.js (I'm using version 2.9), `gridLines` also provides an option to disable the tick mark : `drawTicks`.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    gridLines:{
      drawTicks: false
    }
  }]
}
```