# How to remove excess lines on X axis using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

How can we remove these *extra* lines from X grid lines? I already been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540041/remove-excess-lines-on-y-axis-using-chartjs), but seems it only for remove excess y grid lines. Someone knows how to do it like in the picture below?

[image]

I tried switching the y and x below but seems it hides all grid lines instead of the outside of chartarea only.

```
var x_axis = chartInstance.scales['x-axis-0'];
var topY = chartInstance.scales['y-axis-0'].top;
var bottomY = chartInstance.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
x_axis.options.gridLines.display = false;
x_axis.ticks.forEach(function (label, index) {
  if (index === 0) return;
  var x = x_axis.getPixelForValue(label);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = x_axis.options.gridLines.color;
  ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
  ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/gridlines-display.html
See the drawticks false option

```
                 scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                          display: true,
                          drawBorder: true,
                          drawOnChartArea: true,
                          drawTicks: false,
                        }
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            stepSize: 10
                        }
                    }]
                }
```